# cannot get any santander:traffic or device sensor info from orion since 11 april

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

```
i have a shell script for santander:device or santander:traffic  
(curl orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026/v1/queryContext?limit=1000 -s -S         --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' --header  "X-Auth-Token: $TOKEN"      -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF {
"entities": [
    {
        "type": "**santander:device*",
        "isPattern": "true",
        "id": ".*"
    }
],
"attributes": [
     "TimeInstant"
]}
```

but 
it returns no changes on attributes since 11 April for all santander:device or santander:traffic?Any idea?
best regards
philg

Answer (score 0):

Context information flow from SmartSantander sensors to Orion global instance at FIWARE Lab has been interrupted due to maintenance reasons. We hope to restore it in the short term, maybe by next week (i.e. the week starting on May <s>2nd</s> 16th) as much.

**EDIT:** it has been already restored.

Comment: hello it seems it is not yet fixed .

Comment: is it possible to get sensors with live values (i mean real time values) from another smart city connected to fiware infrastructure?

Comment: It has taken more than expected, but finally it is fixed.